# run api call and fetch data in the background using id received in the new notification in android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using Firebase FCM to send notifications and using Retrofit for api calls. With every notification, I am sending data with it.

I want to fetch some data from the server passing the notification data as API parameters from the server and save it in my app's local database in the background in all the cases i.e. app is running/in background or killed.

i tries looking up for this, some people are suggesting workmanager but I don't know how to use workmanager with notification to achieve this.
Would really appreciate if someone can guide me on how can I achieve this?